# Sending a question with translated text to English for checking purposes

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm not from an English speaking country but on few occasions I have to write some English text. Of course to the best of my abilities. But since this text should be as formal as possible (and grammatically correct as well) and is not related to business (meaning there's no budget for translation services) I would like to know whether it would be possible to submit my English translation for correction to this Stack Exchange site?

I just happen to have a text of about 400 words that needs to be checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but [proofreading](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-about-allowing-people-to-post-entire-compositions) is [off-topic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-off-topic-here/282#282) on this site.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of. Do you maybe know of any on-line service(s) that do proof reading? Community tends to be helpful when it comes to sharing their knowledge so I suppose there could be a few sites doing this kind of service.

Comment: @Robert: Google returns quite a few, but I am not in a position to recommend or advise against any particular site. What you can always do is head over to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and propose a Proofreading site there. (This is how our site got created, too.) I think it has a fair chance of taking off, considering all the proofreading requests we keep getting here.