# Is Python a snake or a programming language? If the latter, why is it choking my dog?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions

We've been getting a rash of questions asking, essentially, what a programmer should name methods or properties. One such was a request for a word that meant both "add" and "remove" because the programmer wanted to have a method that could add or remove an element.

Does this really fall under ELU? The English language doesn't really govern what people can or do call class members and the like. This sort of thing seems more about naming conventions, and in that case I think Programmers.SE would be the more logical choice.

Thoughts?

Comment: The thing is, Programmers does not (or no longer does) welcome bikeshed questions, either. See Mark Trapp's comment [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23642/300), for example: "bikeshedding class names is not welcome on Programmers.SE". (Mark is a mod there.) So the question boils down to, are they welcome on *our* site?

Comment: @RegDwight: Well, I'm fine with your reduction. I don't think they belong here.

Comment: I don't have anything better than the two answers, and I concur: this stuff does not belong here.

Comment: For those who were as baffled by this use of *bikeshed* as I was, by the way: [explanation](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/faq/misc.html#BIKESHED-PAINTING).  Roughly, *bikeshedding* = obsessing argumentatively over trivial details just because you can.

Comment: How is the example above (which was actually asked by me) about naming conventions? I don't think it has anything to do with conventions. I was requesting a word that I did not know, to later use it. In this case I accepted an answer that was "programming specific", but that was by coincidence, I could as well have accepted a word that had nothing to do with programming or computers at all. However, I get your point that this may belong on Programmers.SE.

Comment: I don't understand the title of this question at all. So much so that I wasted my time asking a question that got merged into this one. *And* wasted Jeff Atwood's time actually performing the merge. The daft thing is I've noticed this question several times. The actual matter being discussed would never have occured to me from the title alone.

Comment: Putting aside my rant against a pointlessly (not very) amusing question title, I think that 'internal' identifiers in program code are *way* off-topic for EL&U. I don't particularly object to requests for help identifying suitable 'display' text, but I'd rather not see too many of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Caveat lector.

Comment: @Robusto: To which I would add the caveat that the title of this particular question seems exceptionally bad to me. I notice some moderators seem to have time to make minor stylistic changes to other question titles in the interests of site consistency. So why does no-one think it's worth revising *this* one so it at least nods in the direction of its topic?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Some folks liked it. You didn't. I'm kind of surprised that this is something that really bothers you.

Comment: @Robusto: Well I *am* a programmer (not Python), but I've no idea what the choking dog is all about. I can hardly like something I don't understand, can I? Anyway, that doesn't address my point, which is that I think the headline question text should give a reasonably clear idea of what's being addressed. I really appreciate much of the humour I find in comments, and I hope I may contribute at that level myself. But I do feel that's where it should stay. In-jokes in question titles just make EL&U look nerdy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think anyone else misunderstood the title or felt confusion or distress from it. If they did, a reading of the first sentence was sufficient to put them on the right track. I actually think the quirky title attracted more readership and hence more attention to the topic than a pedestrian title would have.

Comment: @Robusto: I'm obviously in a minority of one then. I must admit I never actually read the first line of the question itself before today, simply because of the title. I shall be more assiduous in future. I'm just glad EL&U doesn't have a 'Wet Blanket' badge, since it looks as though I'd be one of the first to be awarded it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: the title does, in fact, indicate the subject of the question: it's a play on the two meanings of *python*, only the second of which -- the one that's planning to eat Robusto's dog -- is on-topic for this site.

Comment: are the arguments over the title a form of bikeshedding? hahaha

Comment: @Martha: It makes no difference how many people tell me the title *is* informative, amusing, appropriate, or whatever. Either objectively, or to them in particular. The fact remains I didn't get it. After checking many the other Meta question titles, it's the only one that gives me no idea of its actual subject. Which is why I didn't read the actual question, leading me to post a duplicate. No big deal; I just find it odd that EL&U is obviously quite well-monitored for clarity, style, and consistency practically everywhere except *this* title.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I opened the question mostly because of the title. As the question was posted on this site I assumed there was a very slim chance it was about the Python programming language (which, by the way, gets its name from Monty Python) and I proceeded to see what it was about. And, come on, it doesn't look to me so far fetched that the fact that a python could eat Robusto's dog was just a pun. That said, *a pun is the lowest form of humor, unless you thought of it yourself* so... (still I find this humorous).

Comment: @nico: I think I'm not very good at conveying *tone* in my online posts, but let me assure you I'm not sitting here spitting blood and stamping my foot in rage. I have great respect for Robusto, who regularly makes informative and authoritative posts with a deft combination of wit and consideration. I didn't like *this* title, not really because I didn't get the joke originally, but because it didn't convey (to me, at least) what the Question was *really* about. So I never even read the question itself, despite it being of great potential interest to me.

Comment: relevant: http://www.heyokay.com/images/ride%20the%20snake.gif and http://www.heyokay.com/2010/ride-the-snake/

Comment: I agree with Fumble about the jocular question title.  I just don't believe most people will understand the title until they've read the question.  That's fine for a blog entry or whatever but as a SE question it is inviting duplication. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/549/titles-that-do-not-describe-the-question-properly-should-be-edited

Comment: @z7sg: Thank goodness there's at least one other person who understands my misgivings. Even better - actually *agrees* with them! It's no big deal as yet, but it certainly *would* be if we all started wording our questions in this style. So nip it in the bud, I say!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'll not be nipped in the bud, tyvm. However this title may have touched you on the raw, it got noticed way more than a boring title would have. Success speaks for itself. I just hope I may find such a provocative title for my next question.

Comment: @Robusto: Trust me, I shall wield the secateurs deftly and considerately, so as not to reduce your prospects of parenthood. Actually, it's a bit late in the day for me to notice, but I've just realised why this issue only arose for me in *meta*. I didn't originally see the first line of your question itself, because I don't visit *meta* very often. The initial display only shows the titles. Which is the same as *main*, only there I'm more likely to click on *Questions*, which gives the more informative display. Anyway, I shall continue to value your questions, however you title them.

Comment: @Fumble: you're not the only one who doesn't get the title. It's totally unclear to me to, and it's annoying. Sure I can get the topic of this post from its first line, but if I have to do that for every post, then scanning a list of posts is impossible. That's the purpose of a title: to summarize the topic. A title that obfuscates the topic of a post is a bad title. (I didn't find it funny either. Even though I'm a python programmer.)

Comment: @Robusto: success speaks for itself? Are you actually Donald Trump?

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, I am actually Donald Trump.

Comment: @Robusto Are you hoping that winning the presidency will make you a shoe-in for ELU mod? (I know this comment string is over 2 years old, but I actually think the question title is hilarious and couldn't resist...)

Comment: BTW the programming name for a function that does both add and remove is `toggle() `

Comment: **`cleave(x)`**

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't mind questions of the form "What words work in this context?" "Is there a word that can be used for both add and remove (i.e. from a set)?" seems perfectly fine. What bugs me is that they *don't* mention programming until after answers come back that don't work in a programming context. Then an edit goes through and everyone gets to update their answers.

Not only that, a programming-only context is uninteresting and it irks the programmer in me when someone starts asking for a method name that breaks convention; at this point the name is irrelevant. *You are probably doing it wrong.*

Therefore, my opinion is that programming specific contexts are out of the scope of this site and should be closed as **Too Narrow**. If you word the question with an open context you don't get to complain about the valid *English* words not fitting into your program. As a programmer, you can figure that out on your own. We are here to discuss English.

Comment: It bugs you that they don't (initially) mention programming, but it also bugs you when they do mention programming?

Comment: @Charles: Yes. In both cases they mention programming; in one case they rudely wait until _after_ people have answered. If they never mentioned it at all it would be better.

Comment: I would prefer, in general, to have people mention their application since it might be relevant to the answers.  To use your example: "Is there a word that can be used for both add and remove (from a set)?  I looked up ... in a thesaurus and found ... but none seemed quite right.  Sidenote: I'm hoping to use this as a class name in my C++ program."

Comment: @Charles: Sure. I guess I don't necessarily have a problem including a mention to the context but if question _only_ cares about programming then I consider it too narrow. I consider naming methods akin to naming books; naming children; naming companies. We aren't here to name things for people.

Comment: I think we essentially agree.  "(normal question)? My goal is to use this as a name or tagline for my __ company." would be OK, assuming (normal question) is what it says, but "What is a good name for my __ company" or "What should I call my child" would be bad.  Similarly for programming-related questions.

Comment: @Charles: Agreed, with the caveat that the answers are not expected to provide _only_ programming eligible answers. The context helps hone the options into something interesting but it shouldn't become a restriction that prevents the question from being applicable to other people.

Comment: Absolutely.  "Here's my question.  So you know, *I* care only about the fooian answers, but all answers are acceptable."  I've done that before (with non-programming questions) when I thought that asking for a fooian baz would be too narrow to expect answers, though surely someone could find a baz.  That way if someone does know of a fooian baz they will mention it and I'll accept, but if all of the baz answers are non-fooian I'll just accept the best of them as usual.

Comment: I was going to write up an answer clarifying my comment about bikeshedding class names, but this is exactly the point I would make. In a programmer-only context, the question is uninteresting: *who cares* what you name your symbols? Because of this, any question on Programmers.SE  about naming would invariably lead to bike-shedding. But if someone's asking about why X English word is used in Y context, that seems like a valid EL&U question even if the intent is to name a symbol.

Comment: the aim of something like UML when constructing use case diagrams (UCDs), activity diagrams, class diagrams is that you could theoretically send the UCD to a person who can barely read or understand English and they would be able to program your use cases by asking a better speaker/reader of the language or even consulting the dictionary. That is a VERY PRACTICAL USE of English. Why shouldn't it be discussed here?

Comment: @pageman: Programming theory is not in the scope of EL&U. Deal with it.

Answer (score 16):

I would think that those questions are off-topic for EL&U simply because the answer can be given just from a programmer point of view, and users on EL&U are not supposed to be all programmers (although some of them could be programmers at some level).

To make clear what I mean, I will make two examples.

- What name should I use for my function, instead of `IsNotArray()`?
  Supposing the programming language has such function, a programmer could simply reply with *You just need an `IsArray()` function; if you need to check if a variable is not an array, then you use `!IsArray()`.* Anyone who doesn't know anything about programming languages would not answer in that way, but that would be probably be the best answer that such question could get.
- In my PHP script I added a function; should I call it `str_shuffle()` or `str_permutation()`?
  Anyone who is not a programmer would probably say that it makes no difference, or would choose one and give reasons; anyone who knows PHP will say that `str_shuffle()` is a predefined function in PHP, so there would be problems when using a user function called `str_shuffle()`.

The second example makes evident that the answer for such questions depends from the programming context; even if that question would be asked on Stack Overflow, anyone who answers would need to know for which programming language the question is being asked. On EL&U, that would be an irrelevant detail (a linguist, for example, is not supposed to know anything about programming), and reporting that the question is about a Java method, or a PHP function would not help to give the correct answer, as whoever answers is supposed to answer based on English usage of a word, or a group of words.

Also, a compiler doesn't require function/method/class names to follow English grammar or usage; a compiler is happy even if the function is called `x3efdsdf()`, or `MangiaIlPanino()`.
What those questions are really asking is *Which function name would help other developers to remember the purpose of a function?* To that question, only a developer is able to give a correct answer.

Comment: I don't think it has to be given from a programmer's point of view. If someone has a limited vocabulary and explain their situation properly, words will come. I have a an example of my own: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23680/word-for-updating-one-single-square-in-a-grid. I don't think that you have to be a programmer to answer to these simple questions.

Comment: @Whirlwin Since you are not asking for a function name, the question is different. If you are asking to decide which name you should give to a function, then what I reported is still valid; if the suggested name is not valid in the programming language you are using, that is not related with English grammar and usage.

Answer (score -1):

It may be helpful to use the guidelines [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/how-to-deal-with-homework-questions) for homework questions, as applicable.