# Use of EL&U as a lazy programmers resource

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Python a snake or a programming language? If the latter, why is it choking my dog?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-python-a-snake-or-a-programming-language-if-the-latter-why-is-it-choking-my)

I've seen several Questions lately typified by [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24377/in-a-single-word-how-can-i-describe-recent-action), which quite shamelessly solicits suggested names for a program variable.

I don't mind if a questioner wants help choosing suitable terms for his application to display (for example, when presenting user choices). But I really can't see why EL&U should concern itself with choice of variable names.

Would it be ok to flag such questions for moderator attention? Or am I being unreasonable?

Comment: See the discussion over [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-python-a-snake-or-a-programming-language-if-the-latter-why-is-it-choking-my).