# How to decide if a question is better suited for ELL or EL&U?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

*DISCLAIMER*: I am not a native English speaker but have studied the language and am proficient in its usage.

With the birth of ELL, I as an user am puzzled as to whether to direct my question to ELL or EL&U? I do understand that the ELL site is meant for learners(*but aren't we all learning after all*) and EL&U for more expert users posing *interesting and challenging* questions.

I am at a loss at, how to gauge if my question posted here on EL&U will be interesting or challenging enough for the other users? Or, if a question posted on ELL will fail to elicit a satisfactory response because its not too basic.

*How do I pick which site to post my question on?*

**UPDATE:** Going through the answer by J.R for [What is the difference between ELU and ELL?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell) cleared some of my doubts. But this forces me to question if the current process is somehow suggesting users to post their questions on ELL from where the *not-so-basic* ones will be migrated to EL&U.

Comment: There's a good relevant answer at [What is the difference between ELU and ELL?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell). You are entirely correct that it's **questions** which might fit better on each site (either one or the other), and not **users** *per se*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Exactly, my point! I think you should go ahead and edit the question if you feel it can be reworded in a better manner. Cause, I see you have hammered down the point in a single sentence which I have tried to convey in a pretty verbose manner! As for the [link](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell), I am pretty convinced with the answer except for the fact that now I am thinking if I ought to post each of my questions on ELL and if its challenging enough it'll be migrated to EL&U?

Comment: You will probably get different answers on each site. There's been an ELL question here to which I gave an unashamedly ELU answer, but the same question on ELL itself would have received an answer expressed in simpler terms. In some respects, the site choice depends on the answer required.

Comment: Why do none of these questions  (or answers) expand the initialisms? While ELU (English Language and Usage) is pretty evident from being on the title of this page, nowhere does it say that "ELL" means "English Language Learners" as I just found out...