# Is it really helpful to tell a user to look something up in a dictionary?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, comments

I have noticed in many comments to questions regarding single word usage in particular sentence or phrase that a user with high reputation will say something that ultimately boils down to "use a dictionary". At times it can be downright sarcastic or rude to the OP.

Is this type of comment useful? Are we to assume that a question poster does not know what a dictionary is?

Would not be better to provide an answer, even if it is a simple answer? Perhaps after a direct answer is given one could expand on the theory of the word usage if they are so inclined.

Comment: Could you quote some examples, please? You don't *have* to link, or provide the author, but the text would be useful.

Comment: user 1: Did you look "word in question" up in a dictionary?
user 2: Ya, you should just look that up

That is one example I saw that stood out. I don't want to link anything because I do not think the users are trying to be intentionally mean. I just want to see other users opinions.

Comment: In my experience here, I would say that it is not safe to assume that posters know what a dictionary is or how to use it. Also, it's basic research, so if it's not written into the question then we don't know what they have already done.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox would you say that this site for English speakers trying to refine their language skills, or ESL students, general non-English speaking persons seeking clarification, or a combination? If we are helping ESL type people would a dictionary be of any use to begin with?

Comment: Yes, a dictionary would be a helpful starting point for a person to explain what part of a word's meaning or usage they don't understand.

Comment: Who this site is for is answered at the start of the [Tour](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/tour): English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It just seems to me that site as a whole has moved beyond that as there many questions that a person who call themselves a linguist or etymologist wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox I can agree that a dictionary can be helpful, but seeing as they have posted on this site they have not used one or have and found it not helpful. In either case I do think simply commenting "look in a dictionary" is proper. Either answer/comment in a meaningful way or down vote or close the question.

Comment: But ELU *isn't* here to help "ESL type people". That's what [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) is for. Accommodating their questions here on ELU doesn't help either this site or the misplaced querents in the long run.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay, so there is another Stack for that. I have seen there is a feature to migrate questions from Stack to another. I think then the most helpful thing would be to use that feature instead of just saying "look it up".

Comment: Note, however, that questions which can be answered with a dictionary are off-topic at [ell.se], too.

Comment: @Skooba That we accommodate such questions is a kindness. Perhaps it's a kindness too far.

Comment: @StoneyB That pretty much gets to the root of the problem I have with the comment. This would lead into another discussion of "How to keep the site for what it was intended". I am sure that is core discussion of all the founders and super users who frequent SE.

Comment: @AndrewLeach And moderators only have some much time to keep sites clean and on topic. Being a new user this has been helpful discourse.

Comment: The stock answer on ELL is something along the lines of "Look it up, and then come ask us about anything you're still confused about." On the "teach a man to fish" principle that's a much better answer than a short definition.

Comment: @StoneyB as an ESL teacher I have a different perspective on the "look it up in the dictionary" comments I have seen.  There is a difference between the definition in the dictionary and how the word is used.  It's not always easy to see the point of view of an ESL learner or understand how difficult English is for learners.  That said, I have voted to close some "dictionary" posts because they were asking the difference between 4 or 5 different words.  I just vote to move it to ELL.

Comment: @StoneyB that said, I think some dictionary type questions are a good fit for ELU because they do talk about usage or could lead to interesting etymology or usage.

Comment: @AndrewLeach My approach since gaining 3000 rep is to vote to close the question and put ELL as a reason.  I'm not sure how to migrate a question or even if I can do that.  As I told Stoney, I think some dictionary type questions are a good fit for ELU.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Fersher. Dictionaries won't answer all questions, or even most questions. But the dictionary should be the learner's first resort, if only because it saves the answerer from having to guess where the learner's problem lies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers there's a difference between what a word means and how it is used.  As an ESL teacher, I can see why many of the dictionary questions are posted.  Some are best handled on ELL but others such as What's the difference between forecast and predict are quite suitable for a healthy examination on ELU.

Comment: Yes, if someone doesn't know what a dictionary is, we *are* to assume they don't know what a dictionary is. If they do know what a dictionary is, they can easily provide proof by quoting what they found when they looked in a dictionary. Or by, you know, not asking "what does *spouse* mean?" in the first place. This is a site for linguists and etymologists, not a site for people who can't google "wikipedia".

Comment: @StoneyB True.  Oftentimes a student cannot articulate what they don't understand, and they don't know that context is highly important.  I think it's frustrating all around for everyone.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I think some of the dictionary questions can lead to some useful etymology posts...that said, there do seem to be quite a few "hi i really wanna know what does X means?  thanx!"

Comment: @michael_timofeev The dictionary questions *can,* but poor questions should be improved. If there's a good answer, then there is a good question in there somewhere trying to get out. The answerer has obviously got to the core of the question in order to write the answer, so they are ideally placed to improve the question.

Comment: I agree with you, but it's better to give examples. Otherwise you're making the excuses for people who just don't look things up and *ALSO* for people who are close-voting who aren't up to the job of telling whether a question really is a dictionary question or not. So if you don't link to questions where you think those comments are unreasonable, you're going to be shooting yourself (and the site) in the foot! :-) Good point, but needs illustration.

Comment: To complement @Araucaria's comment, there are a number of examples easily adduced to show research which should have been done: [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291481#comment652331_291481) | [2](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291005#comment651132_291005) | [3](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290330/#comment649226_290330) | [4](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289928/#comment648368_289928) | [5](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289923#comment648359_289923)

Comment: @michael_timofeev re differences among 4 or 5 words - I find those questions often are very interesting, because of the usage nuance problem. They've usually shown some minimal research (eg 'The dictionary was not helpful. All the entries refer to each other'). '[What's the difference between bucket and pail?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17860/whats-the-difference-between-bucket-and-pail)'. These kinds of questions are asking about exactly what is not in dictionaries (as you allude to).

Comment: @AndrewLeach, michael_timofeev: Oh. Yeah. Some questions are just stupid. Look it up first.

Comment: Like this one is good form: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26946/difference-between-merkw%c3%bcrdig-and-seltsam

Comment: @Skooba Your question is a reasonable one in the sense that it is questioning very basic and long-standing recommendations on the site and sometimes we need to remind ourselves of the reasons. Questions are   considered closable for 'general reference' reasons, if they haven't shown elementary attempts at figuring it out on their own. 'How do you pronounce "bomb"?'? Look it up, why make us repeat that just for you. 'Why is "bomb" not pronounced literally?'? That is not general reference. Don't make us do work for you that you can so easily do yourself. ELU is not a dictionary, ELL isn't either

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No Stack Exchange site is a tutorial service.
No Stack Exchange site is a research service.
No Stack Exchange site is a substitute for looking in a standard reference work.

**I propose that *any* question which does not show elementary research be closed in short order.** The current close reason contains enough detail to explain what can be done to improve the question:

> Please **include the [research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573) are off-topic.

Very often, there's a comment recommending recourse to a dictionary or other such commonly-available reference; and the closure banner links to a useful list at [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)

Now, the question might arise as to how to decide between summary closure and a migration to ELL, since that path has been opened. That decision tree starts with the fundamental consideration "Is this a good question?" and its supplementary assistants, "Does this show research? Is the question clear? Does the asker actually understand what they are asking about?" That last one means is there some understanding of what the actual *problem* is, not what the *answer* is, of course.

If the question shows some understanding, but it's couched in terms which indicate that the OP is actually a learner (for example, mention of SAT or GRE, but other indications may appear) then it's a reasonable question for ELL. It could be migrated.

It may be that if a question is improved in order that it can be reopened, it's actually reopened and then migrated to ELL. But at least it will be a good question which is migrated. Bad questions should not be migrated; nor should they be answered. They should be improved before anything happens, and being put on hold is the way to ensure that things are done in the right order.

This may mean that the question box sidebar needs to be changed again.

Currently it says this:

> **Is your question about using English?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered,* not just discussed.
>
> - Provide details.
> - Share your research.
>
> If your question is about *learning* English, [ask it on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) instead.
>
> If your question is about this website, [ask it on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead.
>
> [visit the help center »](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)
> [asking help »](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

However, that would appear to support the proposal that ***any* question which does not show elementary research be closed in short order.** And if additional comments help to point the OP in the right direction, so much the better.

Comment: In short: Off-topic questions are off-topic. It is as simple as that. That's what "off-topic" *means*. And anyone is welcome to verify that by looking up "off-topic" in a dictionary of their liking.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Yup.

Comment: @AndrewLeach perhaps to help with this, the sidebar might need amendment.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think a few changes to the sidebar above could help reduce the number of dictionary questions, or at least make them into better questions.  Is there a limit as to how long the sidebar can be...can a few extra clarification guidelines be added?

Comment: There is a limit, and SE staff were pushed to get the current wording under it. However, a new Meta question on changing that sidebar would be better than discussing it here.

Answer (score 6):

Don't regard "Did you look that up in a dictionary?" as a rude question. Take it at face value. It's a hint, a prompt.

#### Either the O.P. used a dictionary first, or not.

If not, a dictionary should have been consulted first. (Probably a few dictionaries, actually.)

If so, then results from that prior research should have been included, summarized, or at least mentioned in the question. Potentially, that can serve a few functions:

- It demonstrates prior research was done, which in turn helps ward off negative comments and downvotes.
- It helps people reading the question better understand where the O.P. is coming from, and where the confusion lies.
- It saves people who want to answer the question a trip to the dictionary themselves.
- It prevents the answers from going in several different directions that the O.P. doesn't want by clarifying what the question is really asking about.

In short, it's not a ***rude*** question, it's a ***fair*** question.

---

There's two sides to the rudeness coin. Personally, I think there's a degree of "rudeness" when a question is skimpy on details and scant on research. It's like saying, *“I just want an answer to my question. I don't want to have to do any work myself, or put any effort into this. Everyone should just be able to figure out by osmosis what I already know, and what I still need to figure out.”*

By the way, there's a reason I put "rudeness" in scare quotes. I don't think most new users are really being "rude" – certainly not intentionally. We live in an online society filled with tweets and snarky comments, where brevity is valued and thoughtful deliberateness is shrugged off. Newcomers to the Stack Exchange often don't realize that this site strives to be differernt.

Every [help page](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) on SE starts with:

> #### *We're a little bit different from other sites.*

and exorts new users to:

> Include ***details about what you have tried*** and ***exactly*** what you are trying to do.
> <sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

In a language forum, that "details about what you have tried" part means, *“Did you look this up? What did you search for? What did you find?”* – particularly when the question is primarily about the meaning of words or phrases.

As for how to pull this off and write good questions, I've already written about this in an [answer to an ELL meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465). And ELL is probably where most "ESL students, general non-English speaking persons seeking clarification" should ask their questions – but [that's another matter entirely](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell/3723#3723).

Comment: Oh, and to address this part of your question: "Would not be better to provide an answer, even if it is a simple answer?" I think, "What did the dictionary say?" can be a simple answer. After all, *teach a man to fish, and he'll eat for a lifetime.* We're a little bit different from other sites; we don't hand out fish here.

Comment: Yes, but do it politely.  I understand that high rep users can get tired and burned out and grumpy.  And some questions are just plain lazy.  But don't say something in a post that you wouldn't say face to face.

Comment: @ab2 - _"Did you look that up in a dictionary?"_ I'd ask that to your face. I'd ask that to my kids. I'd even ask that to _your_ kids. I think I remember my third-grade teacher asking me that once. I don't think it's a "grumpy" response to a language question. _What are you, stupid?_ Now **that's** a rude question. But, _What did you find in the dictionary?_ – I don't find that rude.

Comment: @ J.R. The question itself is not rude. The question itself is part of educating someone.  But some users are sometimes extremely rude when they ask that question, or a similar one.  I'm not going to mention names, and I don't mean you, but I cringe sometimes when I read the comments of high and medium rep users to a neophyte.

Comment: @ab27 - Fair enough. I share your concern. I, too, have seen some comments that were maybe harsher than necessary. Yet I have seen what was intended as a helpful nudge get interpreted as a rude slight, too. Allowances need to be made in both directions; I just wanted to underscore that point.