# Delete [puzzle] tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I just noticed there were 4 questions with [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle). I think it's a worthless tag, so I removed it from those four questions. Assuming that's a sensible thing to have done, what needs to happen to get rid of the tag itself?

Incidentally, [How to obtain "diligence" from crossword clue "horse-drawn vehicle industry"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7433/how-to-obtain-diligence-from-crossword-clue-horse-drawn-vehicle-industry)*only* had [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle), so I replaced it with [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context). I'm still trying to figure out if seeking help with a cryptic crossword clue is a [valid reason for posting a question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2412/what-constitutes-justification-for-posing-a-question-on-elu), and would be interested to know what others think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that there are no questions in that tag, it will disappear on its own in about 24 hours.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true, or at least there's something else going on somewhere. I squashed a few [word] tags a couple of weeks ago, and that tag is still listed. It has no questions attached, thankfully, but it's still in the list.

Comment: @Marthaª That's odd. Although the Info pages for those tags 404 now which suggests they were indeed removed.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing @Marthaª mentioned, but on another SE site. I'll check their info pages though, as that's a good idea.

Comment: @Marthaª A tag that is not used from any question is deleted within 24 hours. That doesn't mean the tag is re-created once a user adds it to an existing question. Only black-listed tags are not created, as users are not allowed to use them in any question.

Answer (score 0):

A tag that is not used from any question is deleted within 24 hours.
This doesn't stop users from adding [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) to existing questions, including the ones they ask, if they have the privilege of creating tags. If we want that a tag is never created again, there are just two things that can be done:

- If there is a tag that can replace [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle), and it is a synonym of [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle), then [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) should be made a synonym of that tag.
- If there isn't any tag for which [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) can be a synonym, and [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) is a really bad tag, then we can ask to black-list it; in this way, nobody could create that tag again. Of course, black-listing a tag should be asked in very specific circumstances; in any cases, the list of black-listed tags should contain too much tags, and those tags are surely tags that are not welcome on EL&U, not tags that are wrongly used in some of the questions.

Comment: I don't think it's really worth blacklisting a tag like [puzzle], because it's not likely to be recreated at all, let alone often enough to be troublesome. The ones that need to be blacklisted are things like [word], [english], [language], etc.

Comment: The question title is "Delete [puzzle] tag." As it is, the tag is temporary deleted, until somebody with the privilege of creating new tags doesn't use [tag:puzzle] again. Permanent deleting a tag is only possible when the tag is black-listed.

Comment: That's just semantics. The [puzzle] tag doesn't exist right now, so as far as I'm concerned, it's deleted.