# Why are requests for headlines off-topic? What about more general work-related questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

A [recent EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291436/a-short-punchy-phrase-that-encapsulates-the-mining-industry-is-on-the-improve?noredirect=1#comment652477_291436) requested

> A short punchy phrase that encapsulates “the mining industry is on the improve” .

It was noted in comments that this is a request for a headline and is therefore off-topic. On the [main-site help page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [meta-site list](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-off-topic-here), a text search (using the browser's search function - not a site-wide search) of each page for the text "headline" produces no hits.

The *headline* label is apt, but why is it off-topic? How is it different from other [single-word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/271044/equivalent-for-personify-thats-not-human-specific) or [short-phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291528/how-to-say-it-well/291531#291531) requests? And finally, does [commercial motivation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291591/conveying-data-collection-storage-using-one-word) (real or perceived) have any bearing here?

Comment: Because there can't, even in theory, be a "right" answer. Single-word and phrase-requests ask answers to provide *existing* words and terms which encapsulate a given meaning. This question is asking answerers to *fabricate* one. In other words: primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At Lawrence's request, I'm reproducing my response (originally given in a comment) to a similar question that he asked me on the main site about why the poster's request was off topic. Here's that comment:

> The question falls into the category of requests for writing advice, and such questions are off-topic at EL&U because they have no long-term value: they are so particularized that answers to them aren't useful to anyone but the person who poses the question. In a sense, the situation resembles a request for proofreading (which is also off-topic at this site), except that instead of asking "Is anything wrong with this sentence?" the poster asks "Can you think of a better way to word this sentence?" Maybe the question would be a better fit at Writers SE.

Answer (score 6):

As Dan Bron says in his comment, single-word and short-phrase requests deal primarily with already-existing words and phrases. Answers can be supported by evidence from dictionaries or searchable corpora. But answers to a question like the one you link to can only be based on opinion. I think it is comparable to the situation with [writing advice and naming advice](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which are also off-topic.