# Can I ask the community to help me find errors in a text/sentence?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions

Basically my question is related to the following question:

[Should we correct (or point out) language errors in questions?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/should-we-correct-or-point-out-language-errors-in-questions)

English is not my mother tongue and mostly i make mistakes in writing which are of grammatical and proper word-order type.

Just take an example of above paragraph, I used 'i' instead of 'I'. So can I put sentences on the site to ask the community to help me if I have made any grammatical or any other error while constructing the sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: it depends. Long answer: you have to be as specific as possible.

Broad questions along the lines of "please proofread this" are [likely to get closed](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-is-on-topic-and-off-topic-here/282#282). However, if you have a specific problem with word order, capitalization, spelling etc., go ahead and ask.

In other words:

- "Can you look at the following sentence? I have no idea if it contains any mistakes or could be better worded." — **Off-topic.**
- "Can you look at the following sentence? I think it contains the following mistake: [clearly state what you think is wrong and why you think so]." — **On-topic.**

Comment: +1 These are great examples. I don't mind proofreading a sentence if the asker makes it beneficial to the community.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is beyond problems with word order, capitalization, and spelling, you might consider posting on Writers.SE.  They will take certain types of [writing critique](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/167#167) questions.  Their guidelines are very specific and do not include proofreading requests, for instance.