# Review my writing

Tags: support, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions, appropriate-answers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What questions are on-topic and off-topic here?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-off-topic-here)
>   [Can I ask the community to help me find errors in a text/sentence?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383/can-i-ask-the-community-to-help-me-find-errors-in-a-text-sentence)

Would English SE be a good place to post a paragraph or two paragraphs of my writing for review?

Comment: Please don't close as a duplicate. I believe it's worth keeping as it contains an explicit answer to a common question.

Comment: @F'x The given answer has a link to the other question; I don't see what the answer adds to what already said in the answers to the other question. Closed questions are then not automatically closed; closing a question can be the first step to delete it, but as far as I remember, none of the closed questions have been deleted, here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-off-topic-here).

You can ask explicit questions about a short sentence of yours, if you highlight the parts of it that you want input on. For example, the following is on-topic:

> I wrote to a coworker: *“if I was in your place, I would refrain from talking to him until he apologizes”*. I wonder if *was* is the correct verb to put here, and if there is a more concise way of saying *“refrain from talking to him”*. Can you help me?

Asking for help without saying what you need help with is off-topic. General proofreading is off-topic, and advice regarding style, long descriptions, and such should go to [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you F'x for clearing this up.  By any chance would you know of a social website like that, that may help me?

Comment: @KerxPhilo: you did notice that link to our sister site [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com), didn't you? Check it out. They have a [dedicated tag for critique questions](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique).

Comment: Ah, I see you have [posted on their meta](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/284/can-i-post-my-writing-for-review-here) now. Excellent. (^_^)

Comment: @RegDwight, yep, after I just learned about Writers SE, I put up a post on their meta.  It looks like I have the go ahead to do that.  Awesome news, I'm excited :)