# Is it proper to propose a paragraph and let people revise it?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I ask the community to help me find errors in a text/sentence?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383/can-i-ask-the-community-to-help-me-find-errors-in-a-text-sentence)

I'm not sure if I could let people improve things I wrote, 
It won't be a long article, just part of it, like a paragraph, that I'll post in the question body,

Will such thing be acceptable ? As I didn't see lot of questions like this, so asking here